Materials for reading on boosting methods
I’m looking for a few references (textbook, lecture notes, slides) on boosting methods that are accessible and not overly detailed. Ideally, these materials should cover the following topics:

AdaBoost
Gradient Goosting
XgBoost


Look at the book Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie et al., Ch. 10 "Boosting and Additive Trees" covers the basics very well. After studying that material, the 2016 XGBoost paper itself should be approachable to a large extent too.
